# character controller for input

Tags: javascript, html, function

Im stuck with my code. I need the code to delete the input text line after the button "UUENDA" is clicked and give it an alert, that only numbers are allowed. Also if there is a space that the function discovers it and then deletes the space as if it were never used. So far that is where I'm at :

the function:

```
function checkInp()
{
  var x= historyId.value;
  if (isNaN(x)) 
  {
    alert("only numbers are allowed");
    return false;
  }
}
```

The input:

```
<td id="history_cont" align="left" style="visibility:hidden">
Haigusjuhu kood:
<input type="text" name="doctor" id="historyId" onkeydown="checkInp()" onchange="" value="" class="txt_left" style="width:140px;" />
</td>
```

and the button:

```
<td align="left" style="padding-left: 10px;">
<div><input id="updateButton" type="button" class='button' value="UUENDA" onclick="javascript:reloadDocumentList()" style="width:80px; height: 26px; font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold; cursor:ponter;" disabled="disabled" /></div>
<div style="margin:5px 0px 5px -5px;"><img src="images/progress.gif" alt="" border="0" id="progressIndicator" style="visibility:hidden" /></div>
</td>
```

Comment: What if `y` in your function?

Comment: it was an mistake, my bad, allso that function is wrong, it doesnt do what I want I need the alert to come when I click on the "updateButton" and if there's characters other than numbers, then I need the function to delete the text in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly there: When the button is clicked you need to check whether there are characters other than numbers in the input field. If there are, delete the input field's contents and alert.

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
$('#updateButton').click(function() {
    if (!$('#historyId').val().match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
        alert("Only numbers are allowed.");
        $('#historyId').val('');
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvms3a3z/1/) to try it out.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the first problem, maybe you know how to delete the space if used? like if there's "123 456", then I need it to go to "123456" like the updatebutton searches from database and there cant be spaces.

Comment: You could replace spaces by empty strings, like so: `$('#historyId').val($('#historyId').val().replace(/ /g,''))`. (I have not tested it, so I hope there are no syntax errors.)